# How use '(' token when using it for searching with ag / awk?

Tags: bash, escape-characters

```
$ ag findVersions( src/java/com/google

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I tried quoting it, escaping it, both were not suitable.

```
$ ag findVersions\( src/java/com/google

ERR: pcre_compile failed at position 13. Error: missing )

$ ack findVersions\( src/java/com/twitter
Invalid regex 'findVersions(':
  Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/findVersions( <-- HERE / at /opt/bin/ack line 2989.
```

Comment: What's that `ag`?

Comment: Silver Searcher - https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher a utility similar to ack.

Comment: Try `\(`: `ag findVersions\( src/java/com/google`. BTW, for searching function definitions and prototypes I recommend a tagging system such as `GNU Global` or `ctags`.

Comment: @arkadiusz-drabczyk, no go. Updated the description. I had already mentioned about trying with escape.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the first argument is a regex, you'll have to both: escape regex special characters, and protect it from the shell

```
ag 'findVersions\(' src/java/com/google
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm surprised that I didn't think of it in the first place.